# When trying to find the voltage between two points on a schematic I get the opposite answer

Tags: voltage

I have the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3X8oi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to calculate \$V_{AC}\$. I figure \$V_A = 12V\$ relative to ground and \$V_C = 0V\$ relative to ground meaning my answer should be: 
$$
V_{AC} = V_C - V_A = 0V-12V = -12V
$$
But, the textbook I am following says it should be \$+12V\$. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Actually it is \$V_A-V_C=+12\,\mathrm{V}\$.

Comment: At least you got the magnitude right, which is 90% of the battle.

Comment: It's simpler if you realise that points B and C can be seen as the exact same point, so \$V_{AC} = V_{AB}\$.

Answer (score 2):

\$V_{AC}\$ corresponds to

$$
V_{AC} = V_A - V_C = 12 V
$$

You interpreted bad relationship subscripts.

Look at the references in your textbook. Surely, the author has defined how to interpret the notation.

Also, points B and C, are the same pontencial so that

$$
V_A = V_{AB} = V_{AC} = 12\,\mathrm{V}
$$

Comment: I guess this must be it. It's strange though, in the explanation before the questions its said \$V_{AB} = V_B-V_A\$.

Comment: The next question also states that \$V_{BD} = -9V\$ but with \$V_B-V_D = 0V - (-9V)=+9V\$.